# Swift - Blurred vibrant background view (like the notification center over the home screen)

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect, uivibrancyeffect

I'm writing an iOS 10 app.

I have a view (let's call it `overlayView`) that overlays another view (let's call it `backgroundView`).

`backgroundView` has some color in it.

I can easily get the `overlayView` to blur the `backgroundView`, but that ends up making the colors in `backgroundView` look pretty dull (no matter which blur style I use). So, what I can't figure out is how to make the colors in the `backgroundView` look vibrant though the `overlayView`.

For example, if you pull the notification center down over your home screen background and app icons, the colors really pop through the notification center and they look very vibrant (not dull)...that's what I want.

To be clear, I'm not talking about how to add vibrant labels on top of a blur view like the Today widgets and stuff. I know how to do that with a vibrancy effect view inside the blur effect view.

I want to know how to get the colors in `backgroundView` to pop through `overlayView`...I want them to look vibrant. It seems that the only way to use vibrancy is to pass things into a vibrancy view that's inside of a blurred view. That won't work for me. And I don't want to use a "snap shot" of the `backgroundView` and insert it into a vibrancy view. I think that would be a mess.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish my goal?

**Comparison:**

Standard visual effects view with blur effect (dark) over a pink box:

[image]

Notification center over a pink box:

[image]

Comment: If the blur was `.light` instead of `.dark`, would that achieve what you want? If not, could you use a combination of CoreImage filters - both blur and color - to get what you need?

Comment: @dfd `.light` doesn't achieve what I want. I'm not sure about CoreImage filters. Would that work on a view? Wouldn't that only work for a UIImage or CGImageRef or something?

Comment: @dfd Also, I was hoping to use the latest iOS visual effects stuff if possible. It's simple and easy to use...it'd be best to avoid getting super low level with this.